# Exibir status de usuários Online & Offline no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

A ideia e mostrar para os visitantes do site se o autor do post esta online ou offline, existe algum plugin ou algum código em PHP que faça essa verificação?

No Xenforo tem essa funcionalidade, gostaria de aplicar no meu blog.

[image: Xenforo Online]

Exemplos:

[image: Online]
[image: Offline]

Procurei em diversos lugares, inclusive aqui na stack em português e na stack em inglês, mas não encontrei uma forma de fazer isso.

Sei que o objetivo do fórum e responder perguntas diretas, mas não tive outra opção alem de perguntar aqui.

Comment: Você vai ter que usar Ajax. E além disso uma tabela que é consultada a cada intervalo de tempo. Essa solução é a mais trivial de todas. Imagino um autor on line que entra no site e altera seu status para on. Logo esse status deve ter um ciclo mínimo de vida em segundos. Quando o script Ajax parar de emitir o status você pode alterar o comportamento da captura de estatus

Comment: e uma boa solução, mas como estamos tratando de Wordpress, a ideia era uma função simples, apenas para verificar se o autor esta online, se ele estivesse ai mostrava o indicador online, obrigado por responder.

Comment: A resposta já se encontra aqui nesse link: [Solução para a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322981/verificando-se-usu%C3%A1rio-est%C3%A1-logado-no-wordpress-mostrar-para-o-visitante/322999#322999)