# Verificando se usuário está logado no Wordpress (mostrar para o visitante)

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu quero verificar se um usuário especifico esta logado no site, quem conhece ou trabalha com Wordpress sabe que isso e uma coisa bem básica de se fazer com o o código a baixo:

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo 'Olá, Usuário logado';
    } else {
    echo 'Bem-vindo, visitante!';
}
?>
```

Até aqui sem problemas, no entanto como eu consigo mostrar para um visitante que não esta logado no site, que esse usuário especifico esta online.

Exemplo: Digamos que eu sou o autor de uma postagem, e eu quero que apareça para o visitante na minha bio que eu estou online no site, como eu posso fazer isso?

Eu tentei usar vários outros métodos disponíveis em outras perguntas aqui da stack, mas nenhuma funcionou, pois a maioria era de 2011, 2012 e 2013.

O mas próximo que eu consegui de obter um resultado satisfatório foi com o código abaixo, no entanto ele não esta verificando o nome do usuário especificado, ele só mostra que esta online se a pessoa fazer o login :(

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user && isset($user->user_login) && 'NOME_DO_USUARIO' == $user->user_login);
        echo '<span class="tag-status tag-status-online"></span>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<span class="tag-status tag-status-offline"></span>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iae Vitor! Seguinte cara, não tem como fazer pelo método que você tá fazendo haha!
Pois isso é uma função... como posso dizer... que será chamada e retornada
Por exemplo, você acessa a página e o código pergunta pro wordpress "Eu estou logado?" e o wordpress apenas responde sim ou não.
Um usuário não é capaz de saber se outro usuário está logado ou não, pois não tem como manter uma conexão aberta pra saber dessa informação do wordpress

(Na verdade tem sim, se ele fizer uma conexão via Ajax, mas ai é só se você quiser {lembrando que, se você usar o ajax num curto intervalo de tempo ele criará requisições simultâneas pra verificar se o usuário está online ou não, isso com o usuário ativo mandando por exemplo um request de update pro banco de dados de 30 em 30 segundos informando que tá online, se quiser explorar esse caso é só dizer que eu tento dar uma explanada sobre})

Mas eu atualmente uso isso no meu website e este é código:

```
<?php
// Atualiza o Status de Atividade do usuário
add_action('init', 'riverlab_users_status_init');
add_action('admin_init', 'riverlab_users_status_init');
function riverlab_users_status_init(){
$logged_in_users = get_transient('users_status'); // Captura as atividades dos usuários pelos transients do wordpress
$user = wp_get_current_user(); // Captura dos dados do usuário atual
// Atualiza o usuário se ele não estiver na lista, ou se ele não estiver online durantes os ultimos 3 minutos (180 segundos)
if ( !isset($logged_in_users[$user->ID]['last']) || $logged_in_users[$user->ID]['last'] <= time()-180 ){
$logged_in_users[$user->ID] = array(
'id' => $user->ID,
'username' => $user->user_login,
'last' => time(),
);
set_transient('users_status', $logged_in_users, 180); // Setar para que expire de 3 em 3 minutos (180 segundos)
}
}
// Checar se há alguém online nos ultimos 3 minutos
function riverlab_is_user_online($id){
$logged_in_users = get_transient('users_status');

return isset($logged_in_users[$id]['last']) && $logged_in_users[$id]['last'] > time()-180;
}
// Checa a ultima vez que alguém esteve online
function riverlab_user_last_online($id){
$logged_in_users = get_transient('users_status');
if ( isset($logged_in_users[$id]['last']) ){
return $logged_in_users[$id]['last'];
} else {
return false;
}
}
?>
```

Tentando te explicar o funcionamento disso é que quando você efetua alguma atividade no wordpress, como por exemplo: vê, cria, edita um post, ou sei lá, entra em alguma página ou post, ou vai pras configurações do wordpress ou qualquer outra atividade que faça logado no wordpress ele gera uma "Log" temporária chamada "Transient" e ela expira em X tempo (em segundos) então tipo de 3 em 3 minutos você precisa fazer algo no site pra poder ser mostrado como online, se você entrar no site e sair rapidinho, seu status de online ainda permanecerá durante 3 minutos.

Você pode colocar esse código no final do seu `functions.php`

e para exibir a informação no seu site você pode adicionar isso do lado de onde queira exibir o nome do seu autor

```
<?php
$id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ); // isso deve estar dentro de um post (single.php por exemplo)
if ( riverlab_is_user_online($id) ) {
        echo '<span class="tag-status tag-status-online"></span>';
    } else {
        echo '<span class="tag-status tag-status-offline"></span>';
    }
?>
```

Espero ter te ajudado :)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado ;)

Comment: Só pra constar, existem outros métodos até mais práticos pra isso, mas esse dai é o mais básico de todos, se quiser explorar mais, dê lida nas funções e sobre Ajax que você verá como pode fazer muitas outras coisas partindo dessa ideia :)

Comment: vou dar uma olhada, até conseguir implementar também o status de ausente, graças a sua ajuda consegui uma base para colocar a ideia em prática, vlw...

Comment: Poderia me mostrar o código de ausente? xD Achei interessante a ideia haha!

Comment: quando eu descobrir como fazer (se eu conseguir né kkk) vou colocar aqui nesse poster.

Comment: Uma solução seria a função fazer duas verificações, digamos que a função faça a primeira verificação em 180 segundos e detectar que o usuário esta offline/inativo, até então a função iria interpreta que o usuário esta ausente, quando a função fizer uma segunda verificação e detectar que o usuário esta inativo por mais de 360 segundos (somando os 180 + 180 segundos depois da primeira verificação) ela passa o usuário para offline. Como eu sou leigo em PHP não faço nem ideia de como fazer isso, mas a ideia talvez funcionaria.